# OBIEE Custom format - changing a column data format with varchar datatype

Tags: oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

In Oracle BI Admin Tool we can use REPLACE function in a measure to change a column data format(varchar as datatype) and then use it in report. But I need to do it directly in report.
How can I use Replace function in 'Column Properties' -> 'Data Format'? or is there any other way to do it in report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPLACE doesn't change the data type. CAST is the function which does that and it's the same in RPD and in the analyses:

```
Changes the data type of a value or a null value to another data type.

CAST(expr AS type)

expr is any expression.
type is any datatype.

Example: CAST(hiredate AS CHAR(40)) FROM employee
```